# how to make install file to change few files only

Tags: installation, patch

For every once a week or once every two weeks, 2-5 files in one application is to be modified - most of them are few lines in a text file.

I could make an instruction to change the contents manually but I want to make an install file to change 2-5 files automatically when the user installs a new patch.

size won't be a problem since everytime the update is required, usually total 5-10 lines in a different text files are to be modified.

Is there any application i can use for this?

I've looked up for NSIS but it's usually for installing a set of files for applications..
It will be in Windows.

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: @PatriceLevesque Windows